# Ruby 1.9 with special chars

Tags: ruby, string, ruby-1.9

I have a lot of these code lines:

```
 @breadcrumb = []
@breadcrumb << ["#!", "Hladať"]
```

It was in ruby ree-1.8, but I can change it to 1.9, but I have this error:

```
/app/controllers/index_controller.rb:36: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting ']'
@breadcrumb << ["#!", "Hladať"]
```

When I delete "ť " and others special chars(ľščťžýáí...) it`s ok, but I need these chars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the "magic comment" specifying the encoding to the top of each Ruby file that has non-ASCII characters:

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```

This is not needed in Rails view files provided `config.encoding` is set properly (the default is UTF-8). You should also read more about [Ruby 1.9's encoding behavior](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_three_default_encodings).